# Classifying space of Clifford Algebra

Tags: clifford-algebras, classifying-spaces

I am a physics student, and I am reading a paper in topological condensed matter employing the classifying space of Clifford Algebra.[This paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1306.2505)

In particular, I feel that I am a bit confused by the notation used around Table 7 and equation (38). Which is about the difference between the direct product and direct sum of Clifford Algebra.

Below is my understanding, when we have two real Clifford Algebra $Cl_{0,q}$ and $Cl_{0,m}$, whose generators commute with each other, their relation is denoted by direct product, as used in equation (38).
$$Cl_{0,q}\otimes Cl_{0,m}$$
Now I want to extent this algebra
$$Cl_{0,q}\otimes Cl_{0,m}\rightarrow Cl_{0,q+1}\otimes Cl_{0,m}$$

The possible extension is given by the classifying space of this algebra. Here is my question

1. What is the classifying space of the direct product of algebra?
2. In Table 7, the author seems to use direct sum of algebra, $$ Cl_{0,q}\oplus Cl_{0,q}$$
   And he claims that the to extent this guy to $Cl_{0,q+1}\oplus Cl_{0,q+1}$, the classifying space is given by $$R_{q}\times R_q$$

I don't understand what the $\times$ between two $R_q$ means. And I don't understand why the author use direct sum of two Clifford Algebra, what is the difference between the direct sum and direct product of two algebra?